# Vue js routing 404 not found and assets

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

i've set up mode to history:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes:[
   ...
 {
  path: '*',
  name: '404',
  components: { default: Page404},
 }
})
```

created htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

everything working as expected wrong urls falls to 404 page... the problem is with deep urls for example website.com/wrong/wrong/wrong images don't appear in the 404 page !

Answer (score 1):

well it had nothing to do with i was missing a slash `/`
this works on level one url:

```
<img class="title" src="img/sad404.png" alt="404 not found" />
```

this is the correct way:

```
<img class="title" src="/img/sad404.png" alt="404 not found" />
```